# pyinstaller python file + exe in only one exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe

py file in which I am executing a .exe file created in C++ (is inside a "data" folder)

Python Code:
`os.system("data\\time.exe")`

When I use the pyinstaller with the --onefile attribute I can't find a way for my program to compile the .py file + the "data" with another .exe inside.

Does anyone know how to convert my entire program into a single .exe? in which I can run my python program and also my .exe from C++ inside?

(I have tried to test with the .spec and with the --add-data attribute but I can't find a way that is compatible with what I want to do)

I look forward to your response,

Thanks you very much <3

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called *auto-py-to-exe* which creates an exe out of your program without requiring you to create a setup file. The interface is great and allows you to easily create and exe without creating a *setup.py*. This also allows you to package your app as a single exe, without any other files. Below is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

You can install the program by typing into the command line:

```
python -m pip install auto-py-to-exe
```

You can run it by typing in:

```
auto-py-to-exe
```

To see more about *auto-py-to-exe*, please visit the *PyPI* page at https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/.